# How to generate32 bit value based on NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to generate a 32 bit value for a username and the 32 bit value should be same for the same username.

Can anyone provide me some information regarding this?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Source code here](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64):

**Step 1:** Import these header files

```
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>
```

**Step 2:** Add this method

```
/Key generation using passcode and salt
+ (NSString *)generateKey:(NSString *)passcode
{

    NSData* myPassData = [passcode1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData* salt = [@"sometext=" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char key[16];
    int result =   CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, myPassData.bytes, myPassData.length, salt.bytes, salt.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1, 1000, key, 16);

    // Hexa decimal or hash key string from hash key data.
    return([self hexStringWithData:key ofLength:8]);
}

+(NSString*) hexStringWithData: (unsigned char*) data ofLength: (NSUInteger) len
{
    NSMutableString *tmp = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<len; i++)
        [tmp appendFormat:@"%02x", data[i]];
    return [NSString stringWithString:tmp];
}
```

**Step 3:** Get salt

```
NSString *key = [self generateKey:@"sometext"];
```